# SSAS: change boolean to 'yes' or 'no'

Tags: cube, ssas, dimension

i'm new to Analysis Services. I have created a dimension on a boolean column. Now users want to have 'yes' and 'no' instead of 'true' and 'false' as result.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a calculated column in your DSV which provides the label you want.

```
case when column = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end
```